# Serial queue for pending offline Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I want to do a write to location A strictly after a write to location B in the Realtime Database. When online, I can use completion callbacks to make this work. However, if I want to support these writes when offline is there any notion of synchronicity for offline capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When online, I can use completion callbacks to make this work.

Yes, you should add a completion listener to the "write to location B" and perform a "write to location A" only when the first operation completes successfully.

When you're offline and you have enabled [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities), then all write operations that are performed, are added to a queue. As soon as you regain connectivity, all data will be synchronized again with the Firebase servers. So if you keep the same logic as above, the order of completion will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks Alex, so in other words my code should not change if the client is online vs offline? All write operations are added to the queue even if they are nested within completion callbacks?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.